# How to implement displaying the requested named anchor using JQuery / JavaScript / CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, anchor

The page has a container div which holds multiple content divs.  Each content div has a named anchor. Only one of the content divs is displayed at a time:

Example:

```
<style>
  .lurk { display: none; }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div id="c1">
    <a name="#c1">One</a> is the loneliest number.
  </div>
  <div id="c2" class="lurk">
    <a name="#c2">Two</a> is company.
  </div>
  <div id="c3" class="lurk">
    <a name="#c3">Three</a> is a crowd.
  </div>
</div>
<script>
// ... something that adds and removes the lurk class from the content divs
</script>
```

The desired behavior is that if someone requests the page using a valid named anchor in the URL, the JavaScript / JQuery will see it and set the various display properties appropriately so that the content corresponding to the named anchor is visible.

1. Is the requesting URL available to
   JQuery?
2. Is checking for named
   anchors in the URL usually done
   early in $(document).ready?()
3. Is
   this hard to get right in a
   cross-browser way?
4. Is there a library routine for extracting the anchor from an URL, or does everybody roll their own regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `location.hash` to retrieve the anchor from the URL. This will work across browsers and will work in `$(document).ready`.

For example:

```
$("div.container > div").removeClass("lurk");
if (location.hash)
    $("#" + location.hash).addClass("lurk");
```

Comment: location.hash already has the "#" at the beginning.  Also, I think you have your addClass/removeClass backwards. :-)

Comment: After taking Ben Blank's suggested corrections, this works.  Thanks!